# how to set a script which will give me data from 7:00am - 11:00am daily for 10days in postgresql

Tags: postgresql

in my Database, there is a table kyc_log so I want daily records from 7:00-11:00 am. records should be in the CSV file.

we will require crontab and \copy command but don't know how it's done.

Answer (score 0):

Summary:

> PostgreSQL still does’t have any native or in-build scheduling methods.

What you can do:

- install extensions like pg_cron, pgAgent - [click](https://fatdba.com/2021/07/30/pg_cron-probably-the-best-way-to-schedule-jobs-within-postgresql-database/)
- use cron job somewhere in your service (java, python, whatever you use), which will be triggered on specific date and time, and will do the needed job

I am not sure if the 1) solution will be able to create CSV file.